# Accessing ApiController Type in DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using Asp.Net WebAPI for a project. I am currently working on authentication and authorization.

I have a messageHandler that will check the HTTP authentication header of a request and build my identity and user profile. However, I want to annotate my controller action (or just the controller) with claims that the action may require (we have a lot of claims that a user can have, so I don't want to load them all).

e.g.:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [LoadClaims("SomeClaim", "SomeOtherClaim", "etc")]
    public string Get()
    {
        if (HasClaim("SomeClaim"))
            return "Awesome";

        return "Bummer";
    }
}
```

Inside the authentication message handler I want to be able to look at the attributes and bring claims back from the DB based on only what is required. For that I need to know what Controller and Action I will hit based on route:

```
 protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
...

            var routeData = request.GetRouteData();
            object controllerName;
            object actionName;
            routeData.Values.TryGetValue("controller", out controllerName);
...
```

So I can get that. But now I need to turn this into a Type that I can reflect on, but all I have is the controller name (not even the full class name or namespace). How can I turn this into something that I can reflect on to get attributes etc?

I am looking into `DefaultHttpControllerSelector` to see how the WebAPI stack does it, and it seems to use `HttpControllerTypeCache`. This is an internal class so I can't create an instance. What is the correct way to go about getting the target controller Type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get access to the type resolver yourself using the global service locator.

```
var controllerTypeResolver = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver();
var controllerTypes = controllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetAssembliesResolver());
var controllerType = controllerTypes.SingleOrDefault(ct => ct.Name == string.Format("{0}Controller", controllerName));
```

You will probably want to do some caching of the results (like the controller selector does). But this approach should work.

**But**

You may be better off moving this logic into a Custom authorisation filter that sits on the controller rather than a delegating handler. Given you need to know the controller type you may as well let the ControllerSelector work normally. Perhaps, if you turned your load claims attribute into an authorization action filter attribute you could just load the claims passed in as parameters and set the principal and claims there and then?

Comment: +1. Custom Authorization filter seems like the best approach with the action context containing all the info you would need about the controller.

Comment: Okay that sounds cool. The reason I didn't do it as an Authorization filter is that I just want to pre-load the claims for use in the action method, not do auth based on them. But you bring up a good point - why do all this work if I can just implement the same thing in an action filter.

Comment: Indeed, to be honest you may get away with just using a plain action filter OnExecuting. How many claims does a user potentially have 100's? I have thus far resisted the urge to say just load them all regardless... if you are using a session token with claims you can avoid hitting the database on each request to hydrate the principal and claims, but even if you must hit the DB each time it may be best to simply performance tune a list of all of them, then maybe top it up with a server cache or distributed memory cache...

Answer (score 1):

If you are still set on the `DelegatingHandler` you could get the Controller Selector instance itself, which'll be way more efficient:

```
var controllerSelector = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerSelector();
var controllerDescriptor = controllerSelector.SelectController( request );
```

Comment: My call to GetHttpControllerSelector inside my DelegatingHandler is throwing a TypeInitializationException| "Attempt by method 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration..ctor()' to access field 'System.Web.HttpGlobalConfiguration.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2' failed"  I haven't explicitly configured a custom HttpControllerSelector, so I assume it is retrieving the default selector. Am I doing something wrong?